# C# Gridview - Checking if a column already exists when adding a new column fails

Tags: c#, gridview, ado.net

I have a GridView with 10 columns. On a certain condition, I want to add a new column called "Expiration Date". The problem is that when the user presses "Search" again (Postback) the column is added again.
I check before adding the column, to see if it already exists:

```
BoundField dtExp = new BoundField
                            {DataField = "DateTimeExpired", HeaderText = "Expiration Date", DataFormatString = "{0:d}"};
if (!grid.Columns.Contains(dtExp)){grid.Columns.Add(dtExp);}
```

But the problem is that even if the column already exists, "Contains" returns false.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is checking whether the grid contains your *new* column (which obviously it won't; you haven't added it yet); you actually want to check whether it contains a *different* column with the same name. Perhaps just loop over the `Columns`, checking for one with `DataField == "DateTimeExpired"`.

Comment: Thanks, it works - but isn't there a more "built in" solution for this?

Comment: @Nir; nope. Generally columns are only added once so it isn't an issue and doesn't need extra code.

Answer (score 5):

You can cast `Columns` to typed IEnumerable<> and use LINQ to check that columns exists:

```
var gridBoundColumns = Grid1.Columns.OfType<BoundField>();
if(gridBoundColumns.Any(bf => bf.DataField.Equals(searchColumn.Name)) == false)
{
    Grid1.Columns.Add(new BoundField{ ... });
}
```

Comment: For DevExpress GridView control: if (gridView1.Columns.Any(bf => bf.FieldName.Equals("FieldName")) == false)